# Where is Facebook.Web?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am attempting to run a sample in facebook-csharp-sdk found here https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk .  I receive the error "The referenced component 'Facebook.Web' could not be found".  I have followed the instructions and executed build.cmd.  Facebook.dll builds successfully.  Facebook.web.dll cannot be found.  Searching, it appears Facebook.web.dll can be found here http://facebook.codeplex.com/documentation but the project is discontinued.  Where is the correct place to get Facebook.Web for the facebook-csharp-sdk samples?  Will Facebook.Web source be added to facebook-csharp-sdk?  If not, seems the project could be abandoned.  Thank-you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find that [on NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/FacebookWeb/5.4.1.0).

Answer (score 2):

Starting from v6 we are removing Facebook.Web.dll and Facebook.Web.Mvc.dll.

If you are creating a Canvas ASP.NET MVC app you can checkout https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-canvas-aspnet-sample

Comment: I see you have removed them in v6. But what is the story, are they going somewhere else? Or should I be changing my legacy code to do something different?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363077/migrating-from-v5-to-v6-of-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk

Comment: http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx