# Migrating from V5 to V6 of the Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to migrate from V5.3.2 to V6 of the SDK. I've got an ASP.NET 4.0 Canvas application. I noticed that now there's no more facebook.web.dll (which I previously used), and found this info:

> > > >
> > >       Removal of Facebook.Web.dll and Facebook.Web.Mvc.dll
> > >       Starting from v6, we are depreciating Facebook.Web.dll and Facebook.Web.Mvc.dll and will no longer be providing it.
> > >       ...
> > >       Starting from v6, you will have to use the Facebook Javascript SDK to get the access token and pass it to the server using secure https connection or use the Facebook OAuth Login Dialog. 
> > >       Decoding signed request (ParseSignedRequest/TryParseSignedRequest) has been moved to FacebookClient instead.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic signedRequest = fb.ParseSignedRequest("app_secret", Request.Params["signed_request"]);
```

<<<<
(http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Glimpse-into-the-Future.aspx)
So that's all well and good. Previously, I had this in my code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Permissions = new[] { "user_about_me" } };

    if (auth.Authorize())
    {
        ShowFacebookContent();
    }
}
```

To change it, I've now got the Javascript SDK successfully loading and logging in my user:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxx', cookie: true, status: true, oauth: true });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                alert(response.authResponse.accessToken);
            }
        });

</script>
```

I've tested this and it successfully logs in the user. But how do I then get it to do a postback and call the server side method that it was calling before (ShowFacebookContent)? I assume that whatever I do will have to pass the accessToken or the SignedRequest so that fb.ParseSignedRequest will work and on the server we can generate a FacebookClient.

I'm guessing that several people will be in a similar situation, trying to migrate off of facebook.web.dll, so any guidance would be really great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your need pass either the signed_request or the access_token.

And also don't pass the access_token over http. Use secure **https** connection.

Comment: Thanks, but in what context do I pass the credentials? I can envision of I set up a form with a submit button to pass that stuff, but I want this code to fire when the page loads.

Comment: what exact request do you want to do when the page loads?

Comment: So, let's assume the simplest example: I'd like to use the graph API to get the user's first name, and set an ASP:Label to that value. Certainly I could do this client side, but assume I'd like to do this server side (as I could do with V5), and would like it to happen when the page loads.

Comment: either set the value in client side using fb js sdk. 
or subscribe to auth.login and auth.authResponseChange and notify the server by setting the cookie/session/rest call. (you could even refresh the page when these changes occur after setting your custom cookie.)
or use server side oauth.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but the takeaway I'm getting is that I can't do things server side in C#. The auth. events are client side events so I could wire up client side handlers. If inside there I did a REST call, that would work, but I'd be calling a web service, not an ASP.NET page method. If I'm misunderstanding, maybe you could give me a brief example. I'm sure many people using V5 have code running in page_load and will have the same question. Again, sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: do something like this 
1. us fb js sdk to login. 
2. subscribe to login event 
3. notify the server that a user has logged in 
4.server may set up custom cookie or session about the logged in user. 5. refresh the page.
6. then use the custom cookie/session to get the info of the logged in user during page_load.

Comment: it is better to use fb js sdk when possible. It will help you decrease  your server load and also a better user experience.

Comment: So if we're to use the js sdk, the C# sdk doesn't come into play and we're not writing C# code, right? How does step 3 above work? How should we notify the server? Are we to call a web service method? If so, do you have any example of this?

Comment: you will need to find the right balance between js and c#. this varies widely depending upon the needs. If you really want to use everything on c#, I would suggest you to use the fb oauth dialog for login.